# JProfiler, check Hibernate cache hit

Tags: jprofiler

Is there any way from the Hibernate probe, to check if the entity was returned from the cache or loaded from DB?
Enabling also the JDBC provides additional info, but doesn't really sasy whether a SQL was fired or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 8.1 this is not possible. I've added this to the issue tracker.